# How do you have a custom 401 Unauthorized Page through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I have a Password Protected Localhost Server to prevent these unknown IPs from getting in my server.

What I want to do is as soon as they try logging in and they get a 401 error htaccess sends them to a file called block.php

as so: ErrorDocument 401 /block.php

The problem is though, because they are not authorized to view anything on that site, block.php does not get called at all.

How do I work around this?

My httaccess looks like this:

```
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "C:\\xampp\\htdocs"
   AuthUserFile C:\\xampp\\htdocs/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user

  <FilesMatch block.php>
  Order Deny,Allow

  </FilesMatch>

 ErrorDocument 401 /block.php
 ErrorDocument 400 /block.php
 ErrorDocument 403 /block.php



 ############### START BANS ###############
```

Comment: What does your auth directives look like?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by auth directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `<FilesMatch>` container to *grant* access if you've already taken it away with your `Require valid-user`. What you can do is use a negative regex match so that the auth is only required when the request is NOT for `/block.php`:

```
 <FilesMatch "(?<!block\.php)$">

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "C:\\xampp\\htdocs"
   AuthUserFile C:\\xampp\\htdocs/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user

 </FilesMatch>

 ErrorDocument 401 /block.php
 ErrorDocument 400 /block.php
 ErrorDocument 403 /block.php
```

Comment: I changed it the way you said. But now it executes block.php regardless of what page I visit. The password protect no longer works! Am I missing anything with this code?

Comment: @Terry it executes block.php because the password protection says to. When you password protect something, it issues a `401 Authorization Required` so the browser can pop up a login dialog. 403 is the code when authentication fails. Since you have `block.php` as the 401 error doc, you see that for **every page you go to**.

Answer (score 0):

block.php had a whitelist of IPs and I added my local ip and I guess any other welcomed ips. This prompted unknown ips to either no the username and password or else have their ip banned from my server. Thanks Jon Lin for the fix!